# Check if current Python script is running in a Jenkins environment

Tags: python, jenkins, environment-variables

I'm writing a Python 3 script meant to be run from Jenkins; However, I'd like it to print several debug messages only when it runs locally on a developer's PC.

I know a possible solution would be creating an Environment variable in the developer's IDE to be passed to the Interpreter and then check for it on start-up:

```
debug_mode = False
if 'DEBUGMODE' in os.environ:
   debug_mode = bool(os.environ.get('DEBUGMODE'))

print('Script is starting up')

(...)    # Do stuff

if debug_mode:
   print('So many things to do...') 

(...)    # Do other stuff
```

Actually, I don't like to force the developer to define DEBUGMODE in his/her environment, so I'm
wondering if there's any other way for my script to automatically know it's running in a Jenkins job and not in a Debugger.

Thanks in advance!

Max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a Jenkins job executes, it always sets some [default environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables).
In your python code you can just check to see if one (or more) of these variables exists.
You can go for the `JENKINS_URL` environment variable as it is quite unique and probably wont be used for any other purpose beside what you want to achieve.
So your code can look like:

```
debug_mode = 'JENKINS_URL' not in os.environ

print('Script is starting up')

(...)  # Do stuff

if debug_mode:
    print('So many things to do...')

(...)  # Do other stuff
```